# What does it mean to equate a matrix with a vector in R

Tags: r, matrix, vector, boolean-expression

In many posts here, people use operations like

```
X==x
```

where X is a matrix and x is a vector in R. The output is a matrix of TRUE and FALSE values of dimension same as that of X. How are TRUE and FALSE arranged in that matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A matrix is a vector with dimension attributes, hence the possibility to compare it to other vectors.  For matrix operations, the matrix is treated as having values arranged by column.  As we can see in the following

```
X = matrix(1:9, 3, 3)

X
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    4    7
# [2,]    2    5    8
# [3,]    3    6    9

as.vector(X)
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

We can see the dim attributes thus:

```
attributes(X)
# $dim
# [1] 3 3
```

If we remove the dim attributes, we are left with just a vector

```
attr(X, 'dim') = NULL
X
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: OK, but then how do two vectors compare? I mean take `x= c(4:6), y=c(1:9)`. Then `x==y` shows `FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE`. Why?

Comment: Thats a completely different question.  The reason is that the shorter vector gets "recycled" to the length of the longer one.  So its like comparing `c(4:6, 4:6, 4:6) == 1:9`

Comment: These questions are not unrelated, I have included in the question that I am asking how are TRUE and FALSE distributed in the output.